# Android reload ListView data from SQLite

Tags: android, listview

I had a ListView that loads data from the SQLite database and onClickListener for each list that opens up to a new activity. My problem now is that when I press "Back" to go back to the previous activity with the ListView, it doesn't show.

How do I reload the list from database again? How do I go about it?

Does it have anything to do with notifyDataSetChanged()?

Please help.

Thank you.

**EDITED:**

Below are my codes to load the ListView under onCreate():

```
        ListView listContent = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contentlist);
        mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(this);
        mySQLiteAdapter.openToRead();

        Cursor cursor = mySQLiteAdapter.queueAll();
        startManagingCursor(cursor);

        String[] from = new String[] { SQLiteAdapter.KEY_CONTENT };
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.text };

        SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.listrow, cursor, from, to);

        listContent.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);

        mySQLiteAdapter.close();

        //Onclick ListView setlistener
        listContent.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        listContent.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                Intent summaryIntent = new Intent(DocumentListActivity.this, ViewDocumentActivity.class);
                listTopic = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();

                summaryIntent.putExtra("SummTopic", listTopic);
                startActivity(summaryIntent);
            }
        });
```

So what to add in the Resume()?

Comment: You should add your load data code to onStart() or onResume(). The rest is pure guessing as you don't provide code...

Comment: Can you post your code? The listview have to show when you pressed back, thats a android lifecycle issue. Load from database in onResume() is not required, when nothing is changed content of database not changed. By a database with much entries it will be impair performance.

Comment: @WarrenFaith: See my edited part for codes.

Comment: @zennon: if onResume() is not the best way, how do I implement otherwise?

Answer (score 2):

You can put your code to fetch data from database and adding it to ListView inside `onResume()`. So when you jump back to your previous Activity its `onResume()` will be called and your ListView will be loaded with the data from database.